# How can I force all traffic for a single app through VPN / Proxy + Open Source? aka App Firewall?

Tags: network, vpn, firewall, proxy, sandbox

I'm looking for an app that is fully Open Source ***OR*** built-in to MacOS as I am trying to use this for security / privacy (to ensure that particular apps cannot make arbitrary connections)

- I have looked into things like the built in app sandboxing via `sandbox-exec` which seems promising, but super hard to find documentation and I haven't seen an example that forces networking through a proxy / port.
- Also `socketfilterfw` which seems to only control ***inbound*** connections.
- `pfctl` seemed promising, but too low-level, I can't see how to isolate an entire app reliably.
- I just found `TSocks` which looks great, but doesn't seem to be maintained.  Was [rejected 9 years ago from homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/3593#issuecomment-623157) for this reason.

VMs are too heavy for my use case.

I believe some refer to this as an "App Firewall", but the built-in MacOS AppFirewall doesn't support this use.

I saw this question "[Is it possible to have per-app network/vpn/proxy settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54557/is-it-possible-to-have-per-app-network-vpn-proxy-settings)" but the answers are 7 years old and include closed-source software like [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com).

Answer (score 2):

> I have looked into things like the built in app sandboxing via sandbox-exec which seems promising

`sandbox-exec` (*deprecated*, according to its man-page) is a utility of restriction framework with `allow-deny` semantics meaning it won't help you to change an app to bind a specific IP-address only (which later could be used together with Pf).

There's a [similar post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/313958/23761) where it's been claimed to be solved with Network Kernel Extensions but source hasn't been shared.

> I just found TSocks which looks great

tsocks (even if was available) relies on `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism which isn't really bullet-proof because it's based on pre-loading of shared library which would further tamper libc calls. Of course, together with sandbox it could be more-or-less secured of leaks, but in general it's too much tinkering. Network Kernel Extensions look more promising, as to me.